# _com_ptr_t::CreateInstance success without regsvr32

Tags: c++, com, atl, regsvr32

I'm studying a program that create the COM object using _com_ptr_t::CreateInstance.
What I'm not getting is that, the code is working without having to regsvr32 the referenced COM dll.

The only requirement is that the COM  has to reside within the same directory of the executable.

Could someone kindly explains why this work without involving regsvr32?

Thank you.

Comment: [Registration free COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx

Registration free COM ... Not hard but tricky.